# two mysql query in one smarty php file?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

First, please ignore the mysql function, I am at the stage of learning smarty so this is just for my test and I will switch to mysqli at the later stage once I know what i'm doing with smarty.

now the question,

I am trying to use two queries in one smarty PHP file and it simply doesn't work. what I mean by it doesn't work is that it only gets the first query in the index.php page! no matter which one I put at the top first, it will not work for the second query!

here is my code for index.php:

```
<?php
// These are the smarty files
require 'libs/Smarty.class.php';

// This is a file which abstracts the DB connecting functionality (Check out PEAR)
include "config/connect_to_mysql.php";

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->compile_check = true;
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->use_sub_dirs = false;
$smarty->caching = true;

// This SQL statement will get the 5 most recently added new items from the database

$storeShop = isSubdomain();


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM $storeShop";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

// For each result that we got from the Database
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $cvalue[] = $line;
}

// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('category', $cvalue);



// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('$category', $cvalue);

// Display the news page through the news template
$smarty->display('index.tpl.html');

// Thanks to David C James for a code improvement :)

?>
<?php
// These are the smarty files
require 'libs/Smarty.class.php';

// This is a file which abstracts the DB connecting functionality (Check out PEAR)
include "config/connect_to_mysql.php";

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->compile_check = true;
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->use_sub_dirs = false;
$smarty->caching = true;

// This SQL statement will get the 5 most recently added new items from the database

$storeShop = isSubdomain();


$sql = 'SELECT * ';
$sql .= "FROM $storeShop ";
$sql .= 'ORDER BY `id` ';

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

// For each result that we got from the Database
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $value[] = $line;
}

// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('storeShop', $value);



// Assign this array to smarty...
$smarty->assign('$storeShop', $value);

// Display the news page through the news template
$smarty->display('index.tpl.html');

// Thanks to David C James for a code improvement :)
?>
```

**I can put the second code at the top of the page and that one works but the code bellow it stops working! so it seems like that only the first query in the page fires!**

**here is my index.tpl.html code:**

```
    {section name=category loop=$category}
<li class="odd"><a href="#">{$category[category].category}</a></li>
{/section}
  {section name=storeShop loop=$storeShop}




  <div class='prod_box'>
    <div class='center_prod_box'>
      <div class='product_title'><a href='#'>{$storeShop[storeShop].product_name}</a></div>
      <div class='product_img'><a href='#'><img src='product_images/{$storeShop[storeShop].id}Image1.jpg' alt='' border='0' /></a></div>
      <div class='prod_price'><span class='reduce'><span>{$storeShop[storeShop].currency}</span>&nbsp;{$storeShop[storeShop].price}</span> <span class='price'><span>{$storeShop[storeShop].currency}</span>&nbsp;{$storeShop[storeShop].price}</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='prod_details_tab'> <a href='#' class='prod_buy'>Add to Cart</a> <a href='#' class='prod_details'>Details</a> </div>
  </div>
  {/section}
```

could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a problem with Smarty at all. this is a problem with the way you are trying to code. Once smarty is rendered the page is dead more than likely, so no control moves on from there.   If it did you would be receiving errors about trying to require and include the same files twice.

Comment: @lagbox, could you please be more specific about the way I code? and what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: do one query ... get your array of values ... do another query get another array of values ... bind both arrays to the template and render it

Comment: @lagbox, spot on mate... that worked like a charm. You can post the same thing as the answer and I will accept it bud. Thanks

Comment: np ... enjoy and good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to bring your second query up in your file before you render your template.

After you have ran your second query and assigned the array you can then bind both of your arrays to the template and render it.

With this method you can pretty much delete everything after you render the template since it is just duplicate of everything you have done already.